# How to increase the latency of the microphone?

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone, latency

I'd like to increase the latency of the audio output.

Configuring latency offset on pavucontrol doesn't work.

I first typed:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=2000 source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo
```

But I could hear myself with a delay while it did not record a delay on Zoom. It wasn't what I intended to do.

Is there a command line to increase the latency of a mic?

Comment: So have you looked at your `/etc/pulse/client.conf` file to see what the problem is? The first line works just fine for me.

Comment: I didn't because I wouldn't know what's wrong. Line 24 says "; default-source =", Line 1 says, "guest-jTtRFm@M4A79XTD-EVO:~$ cat .pulse/client.conf."

Comment: Try to edit your question and put in the complete file (unless yours is really long for some reason). Your line 1 looks like it doesn't belong there, at all, so that may already be the reason. Mine consists mostly of comments (lines starting with `;`, like your line 24, or `#`); these can be ignored.

Comment: Apart from the first line, all lines start either with ; or #.

Comment: @TenzinDorje your comment shows your `cat` command instead of the first line of the file.

Comment: If I have the first line of the file as a comment and run the two "pactl load-module..." lines, I get a '26' after the first line, and then 'Failure: Module initialization failed' for the second line. Anyway, is there another way I can delay my mic?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to first try to fix the lagging webcam?

Comment: @KGIII It's also what I thought at first, but it seems that with the app I use to turn my smartphone into a webcam (namely Droidcam), there's always gonna be lag unless I lower the video quality. I'm not sure other apps such as Iriun would work better.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. There's the lag associated with USB - though USB 3 or USB C may help (if that's an option). It may also be worth posting a question about reducing the lag - perhaps there's something with less overhead (I'm spitballing) that's out there?

Comment: @KGIII Thanks for your suggestion. Given that I managed to sync the audio and video on OBS, I only have to send OBS to Zoom. I've followed tutorials but it doesn't work, so I'll post a question about that.